# access 2010 can't find my VBA function?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to create an AutoExec Macro that'll run a function upon loadup.

I have the function declared and written in a macro called: checkUser

I created an AutoExec Macro, it's code is set to the "RunCode" command, and when I type the "checkUser()" function name, it auto-populates, so obviously it can see it.

However, once I run the AutoExec macro I get this error:

The expression you entered has a function name that Microsoft Access can't find

I've also tried to convert the Autoexec to VBA, and then manually enter the code, when I do I either nothing happens, or I get an error stating that it can't be repeated more than 19 times.

Am I just putting the function in the wrong spot?

Comment: Go to the Immediate window (Ctrl+g will take you there), type `? checkUser()` and press Enter.  What happens?

Comment: Is `checkUser` a macro or a function?

Comment: checUser is a function, which was saved in a macro named the same thing. I just changed the name of the Macro to loginCheck, and kept the function the same name, and now it works! I guess it was confused as to what I wanted to run?

Answer (score 0):

As you hint at in your comments, it looks like you have a name resolution issue.  If your module name is the same as the function name, you need to further qualify the function name like checkUser.CheckUser()